# Using navigator.geolocation, js and flutter_bloc libraries on Flutter web app

Tags: javascript, geolocation, flutter-web, flutter-bloc

I've been trying to use navigator.geolocation function inside a flutter web app using the js dart library.

I've followed the suggestions on this [post](https://flatteredwithflutter.com/detect-user-location-in-flutter-web/) to integrate the JS library.
The main point is how to change from setState() to Bloc/Cubit and receive the result from the async js closure.

I couldn't find a way to wait for the result from the closure execution.

The code snippet below shows the sequence of call and the full code can be seen in my [github](https://github.com/glaubersp-flutter/app2/commit/e9f890a6f0f8f217de5fbef08cd933312119cf7e)

I'd be very glad if anyone can point me to a possible solution =)

Thanks in advance!

```
Future<Weather> fetchWeatherByLocation() async {
    Weather weather;
    final geoCubit = GeolocationCubit();
    var listen = geoCubit.listen((GeolocationState state) async {
      switch (state.runtimeType) {
        case GeolocationLoaded:
          var geolocationLoaded = state as GeolocationLoaded;

          // Placemark addressFromPosition = await _getAddressFromPosition(position);

          var response = await queryRemoteTemperature(
              geolocationLoaded.latitude,
              geolocationLoaded.longitude,
              WeatherRepository.part,
              WeatherRepository.apiKey);

          if (response.statusCode != 200) {
            throw NetworkException();
          }
          weather = Weather.fromJson("", json.decode(response.body));
          return weather;
          break;
      }
    });
    js.getCurrentPosition(allowInterop((pos) {
      var _latitude;
      var _longitude;
      _latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
      _longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
      geoCubit.setPosition(_latitude, _longitude);
      return;
    }));
    await listen.asFuture(weather);
    listen.cancel();
    return Future.value(weather);
  }
```